# bootstraps default form input opens even when the label area is clicked. How do i prevent this?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I want to attach a "browse" button next to this and only allow the button to open file browser, however right now file browser opens if clicked anywhere on the div. Suggestions?

```html
<div class="custom-file">
  <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="customFile">
  <label class="custom-file-label" for="customFile">Choose file</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap's file input is just a `<input type="file">` on top of a label styled to look like an input field; So when you click on the "input", you're clicking on the`label`, which has a reference to the `input` with its `for` attribute.

I think you would have to adjust the styles for the input itself a bit to place it "*behind*" the `button` for it to work like you want to and **remove** the label's reference to the input so it doesn't open it.

```css
.custom-file-input {
  position: absolute !important;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 80px !important;
  height: calc(1.5em + .75rem + 2px);
  margin: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="custom-file">
  <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="customFile">
  <label class="custom-file-label" for="">Choose file</label>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks! ill mark this correct for my question. side question if you don't mind, will this have any impact when working with reactjs?

Comment: Wouldn't know to be honest, since I haven't worked with ReactJS, however I don't think it will have any impact since these are purely CSS changes specific to the class detailed in the example, doesn't have anything to do with JavaScript or anything like that